# How do I get the actual screen edge location?

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, screen, move, bounds

I'm trying to make my form snap to the edge of the screen when a user drags it to within 5 pixels of the edge. My application has multiple forms and is used over multiple screens. The code below snaps to the top edge correctly but there is a gap between the screen edge and form when it snaps to the left and right hand side of the screen. It seems that left hand edge of my screen is X = -4 and not X = 0. How do I determine the actual edge, or is it always X = -4?

I have tried on multiple PCs with different screens but I keep getting a gap when it snaps to the Left or right hand edges of the screen. The padding on my form is set to 0,0,0,0. I have also tried using `screen.bounds` instead of `screen.workingArea` but I get the same result.

I am testing the application on Windows 10.

```
Private Sub Form_Move(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Move
    FormSnaptoEdge(Me)
End Sub

Public Sub FormSnaptoEdge(ByVal FormtoSnap As Form)

    Dim snaptol As Integer = 5

    For Each screen As Screen In screen.AllScreens
        Dim screenrect As Rectangle = screen.WorkingArea

        If FormtoSnap.Left <= screenrect.Left + snaptol AndAlso FormtoSnap.Left > screenrect.Left - snaptol Then
            FormtoSnap.Left = screenrect.Left
        ElseIf FormtoSnap.Right >= screenrect.Right - snaptol AndAlso FormtoSnap.Right < screenrect.Right + snaptol Then
            FormtoSnap.Left = screenrect.Right - FormtoSnap.Width
        End If

        If FormtoSnap.Top <= screenrect.Top + snaptol AndAlso FormtoSnap.Top > screenrect.Top - snaptol Then
            FormtoSnap.Top = screenrect.Top
        ElseIf FormtoSnap.Bottom >= screenrect.Bottom - snaptol AndAlso FormtoSnap.Bottom < screenrect.Bottom + snaptol Then
            FormtoSnap.Top = screenrect.Bottom - FormtoSnap.Height
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: First, why not try setting location to zero instead of screenrect.left? And second, win 10 already automatically has a snap to side feature, doesn't that work?

Comment: This question is not as clear as it should be.  He probably uses a borderless form, so doesn't get the Aero Snap feature.  And when it talks about "gap" he probably means that assigning the Form.Left property moves the window too far to the left by 4 pixels.  And he needs to document the Win10 edition, the Fall Creator's edition is a lot of trouble.  Just guessing, this isn't code I can quickly copy/paste to try it.

Comment: Look at the MouseDown command and examples on "rubber-banding" by dragging a mouse pointer to draw a rectangle on the Form.  Then exploit the x. and y. coordinates for the mouse pointer.   Either that, or just lookup how to fetch x and y Form location from the mouse pointer.

Comment: I tried using FormtoSnap.Location instead of FormtoSnap.Left but i got the same result. 
The form has borders and can be re sized by the user. The windows snap 10 feature doesn't seem to work.
I am using windows 10 64-bit version 1709

Comment: When i maximse the form to fill the whole screen and then queery the Form.Location.X it returns a value of -4 and not 0. I'm not sure why this is not 0.

The above code works it just leaves a gap of 4 pixles. The issue is i need to set the location.X = -4 for the form to be on the right hand edge of the screen. Why is this so?

Comment: I guess ,when you maximize the form the Location.X value is -4 so that the default border of the form (which is probably 4 pixels wide) is outside of the visible area.

Comment: if its always 4 pixels then i can simply offset my code. However will it be different on other versions of windows?